# IFRAME capture event onbeforeunload if parent window close

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture the event onbeforeunload inside an iframe if the parent get closed. I am trying the below code but it does not call the alert.

```
window.parent.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    alert(1)
};
```

Comment: You can't use alert() or prompt() or confirm() in onbeforeunload and need to return a string for it to even show the leave dialog

Comment: @charlietfl. Thanks ! I want to show a message to user if the changes are not saved. I thought I will do it inside this event. What you suggest I can do ?

Comment: Most browsers only show default message any more due to all the abuse that event has had over the years. Try `event.returnValue = 'Message'; return 'Message'`